# Create new data series based on two data series with different sampling time

Tags: matlab, time-series, sampling

I have two data sets with speed and directional data, recorded with different time steps.

One data set (`A`) is recorded every 10 minutes, and the other (`B`) is recorded every hour.

The start times are not exactly the same.

- `A` (speed and directional data) is sampled every 10 minutes e.g. 00.00, 00.10, 00.20, ...
- `B` (directional data) is sampled every hour e.g. 23.54, 00.54, 01.54, ...

I would like to create a new version of data set `B` with directional data (kind of a synthesized data set) based on data set `A` where I fill in the recordings for every 10 minutes from data set `A` and keep the original recording of data set B for every hour.

Example data:

```
% columns: timestamp, direction, speed
A = [732381.006944445  22.70  2.23 
     732381.013888889  18.20  3.41 
     732381.020833333  31.00  6.97 
     732381.027777778  36.90  5.63]; 


% columns: timestamp, direction
B = [732381.038078704   3.01 
     732381.079745370   5.63 
     732381.121412037   0.68 
     732381.163078704 359.56];
```

..and I want something like this..

```
% columns: timestamp, direction
B_new = [732381.038078704 'some value based on value in A at that time' 
         732381.079745370 'some value based on value in A at that time'  
         732381.121412037 'some value based on value in A at that time'  
         732381.163078704 'some value based on value in A at that time'];
```

So the first column in the `B_new` matrix are time stamps of 10 minutes, not the original timestamps of one hour. Ie. we create a new timeseries (`B_new`) with a sampling of 10 minutes. So something like you already showed @Wolfie, but with timestep of matrix `A`.

What is the best way to assign the direction data in `B` as the direction data at the closest available time in `A` while still keeping the same data sampling as A in the new matrix `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily achieved with [`interp1`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) (a table lookup function).

---

**Interpolating to slower sampling**

Let's say you have some nice clean data `A` and `B` for this demo...

```
% Columns: time (0.1s timestep), data (just the row number)
A = [ (1:0.1:2); (1:11) ].';
% Columns: time (1.0s timestep), data (doesn't even matter, to be removed)
B = [ (1:1:2); rand(1,2) ].';
```

Now we use `interp1` to get the closest data value (in terms of the time column) from `A` and assign it to `B_new`.

```
B_new = zeros(size(B)); % Initialise 
B_new(:,1) = B(:,1);    % Get time data from B
% Get nearest neighbour by specifying the 'nearest' method.
% Using 'extrap' means we extrapolate if B's times aren't contained by A's
B_new(:,2) = interp1(A(:,1), A(:,2), B_new(:,1), 'nearest', 'extrap');

% Output
disp(B_new)
% >> [ 1   1
%      2  11 ]
% This is as expected, because 1 and 11 are the values at t = 1 and 2 
% in the A data, where t = 1 and 2 are the time values in the B data.
```

---

**Interpolating to higher sampling**

We can do the opposite too. You suggested you want to take some base data, `A`, and in-fill the points which you had for `B` (or nearest match).

```
B_new = A;    % Initialise to fast sample data
% Get row indices of nearest neighbour (in time) by using interp1 and mapping
% onto a list of integers 1 to number of rows in A 
idx = interp1(A(:,1), 1:size(A,1), B(:,1), 'nearest', 'extrap');
% Overwrite those values (which were originally from A) with values from B
B_new(idx,2) = B(:,2);
```

Comment: So you want to start with `B_new = A`, and then over-write all points nearest to something in `B` so in your example every 6th direction value comes from `B`, all others come from `A`?

Comment: If you use the datestr function on the first column in B_new the timestamps should appear.

Comment: Both of what? I have no idea what 'some value based on value in A' is supposed to be... You've said the final example has time steps of matrix `A` but it doesn't, it matches `B`. Please consider marking this answer as accepted and tweak the results to your heart's content, or clarify the question so it can be answered and closed.